# problem with redux initial state using localStorage on react-native

Tags: android, react-native, redux, storage, expo

I am developing a `react-native` application, with `expo`, `redux` and `react-native-sync-localstorage` to store the application state on localstorage for the next time that the application will start, as token to communication with an api, current user, etc.

I will been testing the initial startup and load the state from local storage and pass to `redux`:

```
export default store = createStore(rootReducer, LocalStorage.find('state'))
```

If the `state.profile.token` is not present the application will starts on LogIn screen, if the `state.profile.token` is present then the application will starts from Main screen.

If before load the state, I insert an hardcoded state to the localStorage, with, token, user information the application starts from the main, and thats is the correct behaviour:

```
LocalStorage.insert('state', {
  profile: { current: { id: 1, type: 'staff', name_type: 'Personal' },
    token: 'Mx2msERuY6342enWEtD2',
    user: { id: 1, name: 'Ezequiel', surname: 'Depetris',gender: 'male' }
  }
}
export default store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState)
```

But when I run `exp build:android` on the console and then I run the application on the Android phone, the state is never loaded and always the application starts from LogIn screen, even if the user is currently loaded.

The file that decides which screen render is the next:

```
...
const initialRoute = () => {
  if (store.getState().profile.token != null)
    return 'Main'
  else
    return 'LogIn'
}

const Router = createSwitchNavigator({
  LogIn: {
    screen: LogInScreen
  },
  Main: {
    screen: MainNavigator
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: initialRoute(),
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal'
})

...
```

I have the permission for write and read on the Android's storage setted on the Android manifest, and I put the request on the `LogInScreen` as:

```
...

  async componentWillMount() {
    await requestStoragePermission()
  }

...
```

`requestStoragePermission.js`:

```
...
export async function requestStoragePermission() {
  const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, my solution was use `import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native"` that is the storage propose by Expo, i been usin an extension of mongo, after that i tried `react-native-sync-localstorage` but i think that you only are authorized to use the storage proposed by expo or some other storage that can be used with expo